# Set theory question

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $a, b, c \in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$. If $\frac{a}{b} \in \left(1 - \frac{1}{c}, 1\right)$, show that $\frac{1}{b} \in \left(0 , \frac{1}{c}\right)$.

My work so far:

Since $\frac{a}{b} \in \left(1 - \frac{1}{c}, 1\right)$, we know $1 - \frac{1}{c} < \frac{a}{b} < 1$. Therefore, $\frac{1}{a} - \frac{1}{ac} < \frac{1}{b} < \frac{1}{a}$ since $a \neq 0$. We know $0 \leq \frac{1}{a} - \frac{1}{ac}$ so it follows that $0 < \frac{1}{b}$. This is where I am stuck. I don't see how $\frac{1}{b} < \frac{1}{c}$ given $\frac{1}{b} < \frac{1}{a}$. Maybe this is not the way to prove it. Any suggestions will help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint.** Check that $b>a$. Since $a,b$ are integers we have $b-a\geq\text{what}$?
Then what can we say about $1-\frac{a}{b}=\frac{b-a}{b}$?

Comment: I see that $b > a$, but for $b - a$ isn't that just greater than $0$?

Comment: $b>a$ so $b-a\not=0$. Hence $b-a$ is a positive integer. What is the smallest positive integer?

Comment: Yea sorry, I fixed my reply. We know $b - a \geq 1$ so $1 - \frac{a}{b} = \frac{b-a}{b} \geq \frac{1}{b}$

Comment: Now we've got it. $\frac{a}{b} \in \left(1 - \frac{1}{c}, 1\right)$ implies $1-\frac{a}{b}<\frac{1}{c}$ and it's done.

Answer (score 0):

This is an algebra problem. We have $1-\frac {1}{c}<\frac {a}{b}<1$ and $b>0 $ so $b-\frac {b}{c}<a<b.$ But $a<b\implies a\leq b-1$ because $a,b$ are integers. So $$b-\frac {b}{c}<a\leq b-1,$$ which implies $$b-\frac {b}{c}<b-1.$$ Since  $b,c$ are positive we have $b-\frac {b}{c}<b-1\iff 0<\frac {1}{b}<\frac {1}{c}.$